# Plot function but blank

Tags: plotting, functions, inverse

Sorry, I am a beginner of Mathematica, try to plot a function, my short code is as follow, but the pic is blank. I could not find what is wrong in my code. Thanks a lot!

```
f[x_] := x + 2^0.5*x^1.5
g[x_] := InverseFunction[Composition[f, f]][x]
k[x_] := x^0.5*g'[x]/g[1]
Plot[k[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: replace `g (1)`  with  `g[1]` in line 3 of your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] = x + 2^(1/2)*x^(3/2);

g[x_] := InverseFunction[Composition[f, f]][x]
k[x_] := x^(1/2)*g'[x]/g[1]

Plot[Evaluate@k[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bob Hanlon. I try to iterate `f[x]` 4 times, my code is as follow, but encounter three problems: 1. the picture of this function goes below 0, it becomes partially negative, which is impossible since `g[x]` is increasing function. 2. the picture of `k[x]` is not 0 when x closes to 0, but it is obvious that `k[0]=0` 3. If I change the number slightly, just like below, the pic I plot is still blank `f[x_] = x + 2^(1/3)*x^(4/3); g[x_] := InverseFunction[Composition[f, f, f, f]][x] k[x_] := x^(1/3)*g'[x]/g[1] Plot[Evaluate@k[x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`